# Enable a low-voltage device depending on 12V...48V presence?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, transistors

There is a DC barrel jack that accepts 12V to 48V from an external PSU. The power may, or may not be available (cable disconnected). Depending on whether or not the power is connected, I wish to enable an IC on the PCB that accepts 1.25V...5V on its 'EN' pin.

My first thought was to simply use a voltage divider to produce the appropriate voltage. But that was a no go, since I can't seem to find appropriate values for the voltages at hand / required.

Second though was a shunt, but it will draw too much power. I don't worry about consumption (device will by mains powered) but more about thermal design.

Lastly, I though about using a transistor (kind doesn't really matter) as a switch (switch the 5V depending on 12V...48V presence) but I'm not sure whether this is even possible.

Any ideas?

[image: schematic]

Answer (score 6):

You could use something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faztwP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LED (could be any visible color) clamps the voltage at 1.8 to 3V. R2 acts as a bit of a pull-down. Check that Vin actually goes to zero reasonably and that not too much current comes out of the EN pin.

Comment: Freaky, not only values, but layout! My label orientation is tidier!

Comment: @Neil_UK  Ha. Great minds..

Comment: @SpehroPefhany that was funny, you both came up with the same circuit! I simulated and they work great :) Which answer should I "accept" now, haha!

Comment: Maybe the one that suggests a white LED to get 3-ish volts. Red could give you as little as 1.8V, green/yellow about 2.2 or 2.5, blue/white/violet all in the region of 3V.

Answer (score 6):

How about this

[image: schematic]

You'll have 1 to 4 mA through the LED, which will give you  nice visual confirmation of the input power state.

R2 is optional, but will give a better pulldown to make sure the enable is not asserted, even if there's some leakage from somewhere.